# Serialise a Jagged Array, and save as JSON

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to save a simple jagged array as an XML, but I can't seem to understand the guides I've seen online.
I wish to save `rawJagged` as JSON:

```
string[][] rawJagged = new string[2][];
rawJagged[0] = new string[1] { "turret idle" };
rawJagged[1] = new string[9] { "turret idle", "turret left kickback 0", "turret left kickback 1", "turret left kickback final", "turret left return 0", "turret left return 1", "turret left return 2", "turret left return 3", "turret left return final" };
```

The array is just string references to use by a SpriteAtlas in Unity, but my problem is purely C# right now. I wish to use JSON so I can use this as a template file and modify it within Notepad++ as needed.

Comment: Please show us the **exact** XML you are aiming to generate...

Comment: that's the thing, I have no idea what exactly I'm doing. I just wish to save that array as some sort of file format where I can modify it myself in notepad++ and then be able to load it back as a jagged array. other guides on Stack Overflow and such have been a little overwhelming for me

Comment: Why XML, rather than say JSON?

Comment: ah I seem to have confused JSON and XML, apologies

Comment: Here is the answer for XML: `
var e = new XElement( "Array",
                                   rawJagged.Select( line => new XElement( "Line",
                                                                           line.Select( cell => new XElement( "C", cell ) ) ) ) );`.

Comment: You would probably be better using a nested list instead ... `List<List<string>> = new List<string>{ new List<string>{"turret idle"}, new List<string>{ "turret idle", "turret left kickback 0", "turret left kickback 1", "turret left kickback final", "turret left return 0", "turret left return 1", "turret left return 2", "turret left return 3", "turret left return final" }};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I... I do not know if I'm being helpful here because this seems too easy XD

But running the following code:

```
string[][] rawJagged = new string[2][];
rawJagged[0] = new string[1] { "turret idle" };
rawJagged[1] = new string[9] { "turret idle", "turret left kickback 0", "turret left kickback 1", "turret left kickback final", "turret left return 0", "turret left return 1", "turret left return 2", "turret left return 3", "turret left return final" };

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rawJagged));
```

Gives me:

```
[
   [
      "turret idle"
   ],
   [
      "turret idle",
      "turret left kickback 0",
      "turret left kickback 1",
      "turret left kickback final",
      "turret left return 0",
      "turret left return 1",
      "turret left return 2",
      "turret left return 3",
      "turret left return final"
   ]
]
```

Which ofcourse can be read back in:

```
string[][] rawJagged = new string[2][];
rawJagged[0] = new string[1] { "turret idle" };
rawJagged[1] = new string[9] { "turret idle", "turret left kickback 0", "turret left kickback 1", "turret left kickback final", "turret left return 0", "turret left return 1", "turret left return 2", "turret left return 3", "turret left return final" };


string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rawJagged);
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[][]>(serialized);

Console.WriteLine(deserialized[1][4]);
```

Which outputs:

```
turret left return 0
```

Ofcourse this does use the Newtonsoft json package for de/serialization.

I hope I have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

got it working like so:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
"turret left kickback 1", "turret left kickback final", "turret left return 0", "turret left return 1", "turret left return 2", "turret left return 3", "turret left return final" });

namespace fork
{
    class Program
    {
        public static List<List<string>> rawJagged;

        static void Main()
        {
            //sample data:
            //rawJagged = new List<List<string>>();
            //rawJagged.Add(new List<string> { "turret idle" });
            //rawJagged.Add(new List<string> { "turret idle", "turret left kickback 0", 
            while (true)
            {
                if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.S)
                {
                    Save();
                }
                else if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.L)
                {
                    Load();
                }
                else if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.D)
                {
                    Delete();
                }
            }

        }
        static void Save()
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rawJagged);
            File.Delete(@"C:\Users\Artin\Desktop\test.json");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Artin\Desktop\test.json", json);
            Console.WriteLine("saved.");
        }
        static void Load()
        {
            string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Artin\Desktop\test.json");
            rawJagged = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<string>>>(json);
            Console.WriteLine("loaded.");
        }
        static void Delete()
        {
            File.Delete(@"C:\Users\Artin\Desktop\test.json");
            Console.WriteLine("deleted.");
        }
    }
}
```